# How to load dynamic data into cassandra table? How to read csv file wih header also?

Tags: scala, cassandra, cql, scala-collections, scalatest

I want to load csv file (Its changing columns) into cassandra table?
File sometimes comes 10 columns and sometime 8 according to this how do i insert data into cassandra table?

Is there any way to load with using scala or batch commands?

How to read csv file wih header also?

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of options here really. You could code your own solution using one of the [Datastax drivers](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/driver-matrix/doc/common/driverMatrix.html), or you could use the [cqlsh COPY](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh_commands/cqlshCopy.html) command, or the Datastax [Bulk loader tool](https://www.datastax.com/2018/05/introducing-datastax-bulk-loader).

The fact that your source file changes format throws a bit of a curve ball at you here and assuming you dont have any control on the files that you have to load then in each base you'll need to create something that initially parses the file or transforms it into a common format with the same amount of columns.

For example if you're using the shell you could count the columns using something like `awk` and then base your actions upon that. A simple example with `bash` to count the number of columns:

```
$ cat csv.ex1
apples,bananas,grapes,pineapples

$ cat csv.ex2
oranges,mangos,melons,pears,rasberries,strawberries,blueberries

$ cat csv.ex1 | awk -F "," '{print "num of cols: "NF}'
num of cols: 4

$cat csv.ex2 | awk -F "," '{print "num of cols: "NF}'
num of cols: 7
```

Once you have this you should then be able to parse or transform your file accordingly and load into Cassandra like you would with any other csv file.

Comment: Thank for your response. But how to load without schema in cassandra. This is like dynamic. Can we use map?

Comment: You have to have a schema in Cassandra before you load anything into a table. You could use a set type to store info but you need to be careful how you update these as overwriting set entries can lead to excessive tombstones. See the docs here on the data types for C3.0: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html